# Django distinct and order_by, annotate does not work

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 tables say

```
class A(models.Model):
    A_version = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    A_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    A_type    = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    unique_together(A_version,A_name)

class B(models.Model):
    B_version = models.ForeignKey(A)
    B_name    = models.ForeignKey(A)
    last_reported_time= models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    unique_together(B_version,B_name)

obj = B.objects.filter(B_name__A_type="Vendor").
        values('B_name','B_version').annotate(Max('last_reported_time')).
        order_by('B_name','B.B_version')
```

`last_reported` is not unique.

Now i have 2 problems.

1. When I use `distinct` instead of `annotate` I was not able to get distinct values. So I used `annotate` as suggested by some people. Still i get non distinct values. How can I get distinct values?
2. If I view the raw sql query for the above query it is translated into `order_by(B.B_name and A.B_version)`. How can I get `order_by(B.B_version)`?

Comment: You should perhaps clean up your example code, because this doesn't seem to compile. 1) Model `A` has two similarly named fields; 2) The `unique_together` lines reference non-existing fields; 3) I'm not familiar with the `last_reported` call: what does it do?; 4) The fact that the `B` model uses the same field names as the `A` model is also quite confusing. Updating things might garner more responses.

Comment: jro sorry was in a hurry. I have edited the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my previous replies to your questions, this is not a good model design. Since A_Name and A_Version are unique together in Class A, you should make the foreign key in Class B to reference the ID of Class A. If you did that all of your queries would be much easier thus you shouldn't have to post all this questions here.

Here it goes, one last time. Remove the Name and Version foreign key in class B:

```
class A(models.Model):
    A_version = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    A_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    A_type    = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together(A_version,A_name)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A) #Reference the A.id
    last_reported_time= models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)

obj = A.objects.filter(A_type="Vendor").annotate(last_time=Max('B__last_reported_time')).
    order_by('A_name','A_version')
```

**UPDATE:** Since the model cant' be changed try this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    A_version = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    A_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    A_type    = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)

    unique_together(A_version,A_name)

class B(models.Model):
    B_version = models.ForeignKey(A, to_field='A_version') #Note the to_field
    B_name    = models.ForeignKey(A, to_field='A_name')   #Note the to_field     
    last_reported_time= models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)

    unique_together(B_version,B_name)

obj = A.objects.filter(A_type="Vendor").
    values('A_name','A_version').annotate(last_time=Max('B__last_reported_time')).
    order_by('A_name','A_version')
```

Comment: I have now replied but when I look at your models I think you need to explain what functions Model A and Model B should have. What are you trying to accomplish with your models?

Comment: Mikael, Actually I Cant change the models. Its has already been designed by someone else and am not supposed to amend it in any way.I cant remove the foreign keys nor can I insert any attribute. Am supposed to retrieve all the distinct data in table B which have a particular A_type and order them by name and version

Comment: I have updated my reply with a new suggestion. I have not been able to test this myself so give it a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: Mikael, I cannot use to_field because it tells B_version should have unique set to True which i cant do. I have used 'in' instead to join the tables and now it works